# Convert LineString / MultiLineString geometries to lat lon

Tags: python, coordinates, geojson, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I am using this Mapillary endpoint: `https://tiles.mapillary.com/maps/vtp/mly1_public/2/{zoom_level}/{x}/{y}?access_token={}` and getting such responses back (see photo). Also, here is the [Mapillary documentation](https://www.mapillary.com/developer/api-documentation/).

It is not quite clear to me what the nested coordinate lists in the response represent. By the looks of it, I initially thought it may have to do with pixel coordinates. But judging by the context (the API documentation) and the endpoint I am using, I would say that is not the case. Also, I am not sure if the json response you see in the picture is valid geojson. Some online formatters did not accept it as valid.

**I would like to find the bounding box of the "sequence"**. For context, that would be the minimal-area rectangle defined by two lat, lon positions that fully encompasses the geometry of the so-called "sequence"; and a "sequence" is basically a series of photos taken during a vehicle/on-foot trip, together with the metadata associated with the photos (metadata is available using another endpoint, but that is just for context).

**My question is**: is it possbile to turn the coordinates you see in the pictures into (lat,lon)? Having those, it would be easy for me to find the bounding box of the sequence. And if so, how? Also, please notice that some of the nested lists are of type `LineString` while others are `MultiLineString` (which I read about the difference here: [help.arcgis.com](https://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/concepts/geometry/shapes/types.htm#:%7E:text=The%20interior%20of%20a%20linestring,is%20a%20collection%20of%20linestrings.), hope this helps) [image: respone_from_API]

**Minimal reproducible code snippet:**

```py
import json
import requests
import mercantile
import mapbox_vector_tile as mvt

ACCESS_TOKEN = 'XXX' # can be provided from here: https://www.mapillary.com/dashboard/developers

z6_tiles = list(mercantile.tiles( #us_west_coast_bbox
    west=-125.066423,
    south=42.042594,
    east=-119.837770,
    north=49.148042,
    zooms=6
))

# pprint(z6_tiles)
vector_tiles_url = 'https://tiles.mapillary.com/maps/vtp/mly1_public/2/{}/{}/{}?access_token={}'
for tile in z6_tiles:
    res = requests.get(vector_tiles_url.format(tile.z,tile.x,tile.y,ACCESS_TOKEN))
    res_json = mvt.decode(res.content)
    with open('idea.json','w+') as f:
        json.dump(res_json, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: It's almost certainly pixel coordinates within that image.  You already know the lat/long coordinates for the image edges (you provided them).  Unless you're spanning a vast area,  you can map those points to lat/long just by linear interpolation, right?

Comment: You are right. But the “unless” part is exactly my scenario..

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it matters.  There will always be distortion when mapping that large of an area to a rectangle, and linear interpolation will just give you the same distortion the map has.  The coordinates will be as accurate as the display.

Comment: @TimRoberts hello, again! I'm coming back to your comments, because I realised I did not fully understand what you meant. I now have smaller regions ie: tiles of zoom level 14, like this one https://tile.openstreetmap.org/14/8529/5974.png. 

How do I transpose the coordinates (that look just like in the picture) to (lat, lon)?

Comment: It's linear interpolation.  If you have the corners, then you know the width and height of the region in fractional degrees.  For example, if the image size is 800x600 pixels, and you want the point at 100,200, you take  `100 x (width in degrees) / 800 + left edge longitude`, and `200 x (height in degrees) / 600 + top edge latitude`.

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry, I wanted to edit my comment, but I couldn't any longer. Here's the actual comment I intended to post: 

ooh, I see. Thanks a lot! Just one thing to point out: longitude degrees increase "from left to right' (when looking at a map), so I understand the `left edge longitude` part; therefore, wasn't it `lower edge latitude` instead of `top edge latitude` actually? Because degrees increase starting from the South Pole towards the North Pole.

Comment: So, you adjust the sign.  `top edge latitude - 200 x (height) / 600`.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, that works too. Either that or what I mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this `get_normalized_coordinates` is the solution I was looking for. Please take this with a grain of salt, as I did not fully test it yet. Will try to and then I will update my answer. Also, please be cautious, because for tiles closer to either the South or the North Pole, the `Z14_TILE_DMD_WIDTH` constant will not be the one you see, but something more like: `0.0018958715374282065`.

```py
Z14_TILE_DMD_WIDTH = 0.02197265625
Z14_TILE_DMD_HEIGHT = 0.018241950298914844
def get_normalized_coordinates(bbox: mercantile.LngLatBbox, 
                               target_lat: int, 
                               target_lon: int, 
                               extent: int=4096): # 4096 is Mapillary's default
    """
    Returns lon,lat tuple representing real position on world map of a map feature.
    """

    min_lon, min_lat, _, _ = bbox
    return min_lon + target_lon / extent * Z14_TILE_DMD_WIDTH, 
           min_lat + target_lat / extent * Z14_TILE_DMD_HEIGHT
```

And if you are wondering how I came with the constants that you see, I simply iterated over the list of tiles that I am interested in and checked to make sure they all have the same width/height size (this might have not been the case, keeping in mind what I mentioned above about tiles closer to one of the poles - I think this is called "distortion", not sure). Also, for context: these tiles I iterated over are within this bbox: (-125.024414, 31.128199, -108.896484, 49.152970) (min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat; US west coast) which I believe is also why all the tiles have the same width/height sizes.

```py
set_test = set()
for tile in relevant_tiles_set:
    curr_bbox = mercantile.bounds(list_relevant_tiles_set[i])
    dm_width_diff: float = curr_bbox.east - curr_bbox.west
    dm_height_diff: float = curr_bbox.north - curr_bbox.south
    set_test.add((dm_width_diff, dm_height_diff))
set_test
```

output:

`{(0.02197265625, 0.018241950298914844}`

UPDATE: forgot to mention that you actually do not need to compute those WIDTH, HEIGHT constants. You just replace those with `(max_lon - min_lon)` and `(max_lat - min_lat)` respectively. What I did with those constants was something for testing purposes only